# How to use grep or awk to process a specific column ( with keywords from text file )

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I've tried many combinations of grep and awk commands to process text from file.

This is a list of customers of this type:

```
John,Mills,81,Crescent,New York,NY,john@mills.com,19/02/1954
```

I am trying to separate these records into two categories, MEN and FEMALES.

I have a list of some 5000 Female Names , all in plain text , all in one file.

How can I "grep" the first column ( since I am only matching first names) but still printing the entire customer record ?

I found it easy to "cut" the first column and `grep --file=female.names.txt`, but this way it's not going to print the entire record any longer.

I am aware of the awk option but in that case I don't know how to read the female names from file.

```
awk -F ',' ' { if($1==" ???Filename??? ") print $0} '
```

Many thanks !

Comment: Ummm ... I wouldn't bet my right hand on the accuracy of your list. Why?  Because **Andrea** is a "female" name in Anglo-saxon speaking countries, but "male" in e.g. Italy.  Then there's cases like Shannon, which can be either.  Just saying.

Comment: The opposite of Female is Male, not Men. This makes no sense as there's a TON of English-language names alone that apply to males or females (Leslie, Jackie, Hunter, Skylar, Billy, Erin, Reece, etc., etc...) - I can't imagine a list of 5000 "female names" within which there aren't some names that make some guys sit up and say "hey!".

Comment: Both of you are correct.

I did some frequency analysis on "American" names and then I moved on to Europe. The 5000 names are a compilation of American , European and some Middle Eastern. I don't have anything from Africa yet. Your comments are going to make me have to work more now guys :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with Awk:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} ($1 in a)' female.names.txt file.csv
```

Would print the lines of your csv file that contain first names of any found in your file `female.names.txt`.

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} !($1 in a)' female.names.txt file.csv
```

Would output lines not found in `female.names.txt`.

This assumes the format of your `female.names.txt` file is something like:

```
Heather
Irene
Jane
```

Comment: Hey John, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but as soon as I move down the columns, awk doesn't match the names any longer.
I've tried:
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$3]; next} ($1 in a)' , so changing column position to 3. How exactly does that work please ?

Comment: In which file are you changing columns, the csv file or the list of names?  If you want to match the 3rd column in the csv file, you could just change `$1 in a` to `$3 in a`.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is Perl, which can be useful if you're not super-familiar with awk.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -anF,
use strict;
our %names;

BEGIN {
    while (<ARGV>) {
        chomp;
        $names{$_} = 1;
    }
}

print if $names{$F[0]};
```

To run (assume you named this file `filter.pl`):

```
perl filter.pl female.names.txt < records.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your helpful feedback !

I've tried both methods, they work ! Sigh :) 


Just another question for Chris' method.

How will I be able to change columns and delimiters ? 

Say for example I have shoescategory;John;Mills;addres; ; ; ; ; ;

I will need to parse the second column with ';' as delimiter.


Thanks again !!

Comment: @user3920489 Change the `,` in the first line to `;` instead, and use `$F[1]` instead of `$F[0]` for accessing the second column.

Comment: In what way is that perl solution better than an awk solution? The perl solution seems to be lengthier, harder to read, and is not as portable as an awk solution - what am I missing?

Comment: @EdMorton The Perl version uses a hash table, giving amortised-constant-time lookups for each row. From what I understand of the awk solution from John, it uses arrays, so the `$1 in a` check would be linear on the length of the name list---for each row. This would have disastrous performance if the list of names is long and the data has many rows.

Comment: No, you're wrong, awk arrays are implemented as a hash table. `$1 in a` is  hash lookup which is why when you write a loop like `for (i in a)...` you get what appears to be random indices instead of, say, numeric order since the `in` operator by default accesses the array in the order the elements are stored in the hash table. As an aside - you can modify that behavior and specify a specific access order in GNU awk with the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` setting.

Comment: @EdMorton Ah, that's good to know. Thanks! Well, I'll be happy to remove my answer in that case.

Comment: It's fine to post an answer in perl, no need to delete it, I was just wondering about the rationale behind the statement that perl is better than awk since AFAIK awk is better than perl in every important way for manipulating text files. Maybe just edit your answer to remove that statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep --file=<(sed 's/.*/^&,/' female.names.txt) datafile.csv
```

This changes all the names in the list of female names to the regular expression `^name,` so it only matches at the beginning of the line and followed by a comma. Then it uses process substitution to use that as the file to match against the data file.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've come up with the following:

Suppose, you have a file having the following lines in a file named `test.txt`:

`abe 123 bdb 532`

`xyz 593 iau 591`

Now you want to find the lines which include the first field having the first and last letters as vowels. If you did a simple `grep` you would get both of the lines but the following will give you the first line only which is the desired output:

```
egrep "^([0-z]{1,} ){0}[aeiou][0-z]+[aeiou]" test.txt
```

Then you want to the find the lines which include the third field having the first and last letters as vowels. Similary, if you did a simple `grep` you would get both of the lines but the following will give you the second line only which is the desired output:

```
egrep "^([0-z]{1,} ){2}[aeiou][0-z]+[aeiou]" test.txt
```

The value in the first curly braces `{1,}` specifies that the preceding character which ranges from 0 to z according to the ASCII table, can occur any number of times. After that, we have the field separator `space in this case`. Change the value within the second curly braces `{0} or {2}` to the `desired field number-1`. Then, use a regular expression to mention your criteria.